# NSTextField to open local html in browser

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to create a clickable text (hyperlink text) in cocoa. On click it should open the content in browser instead of opening in Finder. How can I get it done?

This is the code I am trying

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"file:///Users/abc/index.html"]];

NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Help"];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attrString length]);
[attrString beginEditing];

[attrString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[url absoluteString] range:range];

// make the text appear in blue
[attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor blueColor] range:range];

// make the text appear with an underline
[attrString addAttribute:
 NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSSingleUnderlineStyle] range:range];

[attrString endEditing];
```

Thanks In Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sub class `NSTextField` and override `mouseDown` method.

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
    NSLog(@"Here"); // Delegate action back to View Controller.
}
```

Then you can listen to click events on the text. You can even change the cursor to get a pointingHand in `resetCursorRects`.

```
-(void)resetCursorRects
{
    [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
}
```

Comment: Do you know how can I do that using swift?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create a button.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button setTitle:@"Click here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Then implement a new method that gets called whenever the user touches the button and opens your url in Safari.

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```